# How can I check over-/underflow when converting double to int in C++?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, static-cast

when learning about static_cast and dynamic_cast i saw an advice about additional checking on overflow and underflow when casting double type into int one. how can i do that here?

```cpp
    double value1{ 4.8967 };
    int value2 = static_cast<int>(value1);
    std::cout << value2 << std::endl;
```

i tried searching here and there only to found an arithmetic over-/underflow which seems not quite the case here. i'd appresiate a couple of links where i can read about it more specifically

Comment: To avoid [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) you have to check whether the values would over- or underflow *before* doing the conversion. You can't check if overflow happened *after* the fact, you have to avoid the possibility of it ever possibly happening in the first place.

Comment: You can look at `boost::numeric_cast`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/numeric/conversion/.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `static_cast`; `int value2 = value1;` is legal and does exactly the same thing. Yes, you might have a nagging compiler that tells you that you're probably not smart enough to understand the code that you wrote, and insists that you decorate your code with a redundant cast. :-(

Comment: @PeteBecker conciseness and readability are two very different concepts. An explicit cast in such a case express very clearly the intent and you don't have to wonder whether the author of this code made a mistake or not.

Comment: @PeteBecker You might (hopefully) have a QA department that will tell you something about silent casts, ignoring compiler warnings, and not running your compiler in the strictest error-checking mode possible.

Comment: @Zejj Actually I'd be more likely to suspect a mistake with the explicit cast.  Useless casts are a code smell that hide (by shutting up compiler warnings) significantly more serious problems

Comment: @DevSolar -- there is no such thing as a "silent cast". A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Yes, sometimes an implicit conversion can be a mistake. But the compiler writer doesn't know what my code is supposed to do, and compiler writers shouldn't be dictating coding style.

Comment: @DevSolar -- "QA department says do this..." isn't a valid argument. It's just restating the underlying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) create a helper function to avoid overflowing. You'd then get the minimum possible `int` value if there would be an underflow or the maximum possible `int` value if there would be an overflow.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>  // numeric_limits

template <class R, class T>
R anti_overflow_clamp(T value) {
    if (value <= std::numeric_limits<R>::lowest()) [[unlikely]]
        return std::numeric_limits<R>::lowest();

    if (std::numeric_limits<R>::max() <= value) [[unlikely]]
        return std::numeric_limits<R>::max();

    return static_cast<R>(value);
}

int main() {
    double value1 = -9872034875209384574237698276453978264398576.0;

    auto value2 = anti_overflow_clamp<int>(value1);

    std::cout << value2 << '\n'; // min value for int
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())` is exact or safe to convert back to an `int`.  It is completely possible that the nearest representable value is one greater than `INT_MAX`, and you're right back in the land of undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt True. I deleted that part and made a helper function to do the clamping instead.

Comment: `if (std::numeric_limits<R>::max() < value)` is still going to have an inexact left operand and fail to catch an out-of-range value.  You need `<=` or else possibly `std::nexttoward`

Comment: This particular problem is quite tricksy.

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed. Many traps :-)

Comment: And I think it may still be possible for the conditionals to take the wrong branch due to [excess precision](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#6) :(

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, that sounds nasty. Do you know how to setup something to display that behaviour? I can't come up with any ideas myself.

Comment: Actually I think excess precision can change the operands in that conditional, but should still match the entire range of representable values that needs to be clamped.  The problem would only arise if `value` is carried with excess precision but the operand `std::numeric_limits<R>::max()` is converted with the basic precision.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see. I'll have to look closer at that later. Need to run...